# Kafka Spout Not Emitting Data?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I borrowed the code from internet to create a storm spout that reads data from remote kafka cluster. I have checked connectivity between storm cluster and kafka cluster and it is okay. I can read the topics via kafka command line tools. But when I submit the topology it spout does't emit any thing.  Please help !!

```
public class KafkaTopology {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
    hosts.add("10.87.36.80:2181");
  // SpoutConfig kafkaConf = new SpoutConfig(StaticHosts.fromHostString(hosts, 3), "test", "/kafkastorm", "discovery");
    SpoutConfig kafkaConf  = new SpoutConfig(new ZkHosts("localhost:2181"),
               "test",      // Kafka topic to read from
               "/test", // Root path in Zookeeper for the spout to store consumer offsets
               "clickdata");  // ID for storing consumer offsets in Zookeeper

    kafkaConf.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());

    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaConf);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("spout", kafkaSpout, 2);
    builder.setBolt("printer", new PrinterBolt())
            .shuffleGrouping("spout");

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);

    if(args!=null && args.length > 0) {
        config.setNumWorkers(3);

        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], config, builder.createTopology());
    } else {        
        config.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("kafka", config, builder.createTopology());

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        cluster.shutdown();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How you do observe your topology? Using Storm UI? Did you check the logs for error messages? How do you start you topology (within some IDE or using `storm jar` command)?

Comment: I am observing logs of worker nodes & as well as ui too. Also topology was submitted with jar command.

Comment: I you test connection from storm cluster to kafka cluster, which storm cluster node did you use (nimbus, all)? I am also wondering if `new ZkHosts("localhost:2181")` might be the problem. What is your ZK setup?

Comment: I am using hortonworks sandbox. Localhost corresponds to zookeeper. Also log shows I am connected to kafka cluster. I will paste logs.

Comment: do you have the zookeeper running locally? what about your kafka is also local? Your kafkaspout looks okay...

Answer (score 0):

`hosts.add("10.87.36.80:2181");`  this supposed to be the address of the Kafka brokers , the port `2181` is generally used by Zookeepers.